# Settings scss doesn't work in Foundation

Tags: html, css, frameworks, sass, zurb-foundation

I tried for the first time today to use SASS. And Foundation.
I followed many posts to eventually end up with a full (quiet) working folder for my project.
I got an example HTLM from Foundation, and everything seems to work fine !
I can add or remove HTML without any problem, it still works.

So I tried to start edit _settings.scss.
Unfortunately it changes nothing, and I just don't know why.

I don't know what to do next...

Comment: Have you compiled the `.scss` to `.css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SCSS to work you have to compile it after each save.

I recommend installing Ruby on your computer and using the command prompt to "watch" the file for changes.

basically something like this.

```
sass --watch styles.scss:styles.css
```

This will tell SASS to watch for changes on any files associated with styles.scss or whatever you named your master SCSS sheet. changes to _settings or _mixins etc will all be picked up and re-compiled after the save.

Check out this link for some basic info: http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: I watched a video, he just edited _settings.scss, refresh page and it worked ! I just don't get why

Comment: He probably had the `watch` command running, which auto compiles the `.scss` to `CSS` in the background. One way to do it would be to use Compass - http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/3.2.5/compass.php

Comment: Well, I tried Compass, but it didn't work, he always asked me about nodeJS, while it was ALREADY install on my machine

Well, actually, I didn't not really understand each steps.
I installed Ruby, and launch it with my Command Prompt. ok
But after that, Ruby, Compass, NodeJS or any website doesn't give me clear instruction on what to do. And I'm just lost :(

Oh, and i didn't find your page on foundation ... must be hide somewhere, I only had this : http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

Comment: Ok so you have ruby installed. Pull up the Ruby prompt and navigate to where you are keeping your SCSS files.

Once there use the command I outlined in the answer above and replace the styles.scss and styles.css with your SCSS file and your CSS file respectively.

Comment: Tried it : http://puu.sh/7KhRK.png
Foundation, and Grunt (obviously ? :s) put my CSS "app.css" and my mastersheet "app.scss" in different folders. Not sure it's okay

Comment: Something is out of sorts on your _settings.scss it cannot find the "foundation/component/dropdown" Are your paths correct?

Comment: I don't know... the last thing I did was : creating the folder with the command prompt, then type : grunt build. And it created a lot of files I mainly don't understand.
It looks like this : http://puu.sh/7KimL.png

In the video, after this, he edits SCSS file by changing a color, then save and refresh pages. That's all.

Comment: Ok the first problem is that SASS is compiling the CSS into the SASS folder and not into the CSS folder you have there so you would have to manually move the file from the SASS folder over to the CSS one to test your changes.

Now.. the second problem as to why SASS is giving you a syntax error is a little harder to figure out but for starters you seem to be missing a folder called FOUNDATION which is where the _settings.scss is trying to make calls from.

Comment: I don't understand compiling. And how it works :(
I saw the video of the guy editing with sublime text a SCSS file, then refresh, then BOUM. I just want the same thing, but as I don't know how to install/use : Ruby, Compass, SASS, or anything I'm lost. I don't know where FOUNDATION folder should be.

Comment: For that to work you need to have a ruby Prompt window running on the background by typing in the sass --watch command. The sass --watch command takes in two arguments. your main SASS file name as the input and the desired CSS file name as the output separated by a semi-colon.

So when you are working away on sublime after running this command it is always compiling a new CSS for you automatically.

In your case you would use the following command without the quotes "sass --watch app.scss:app.css" and hit enter

Comment: As for your foundation folder I am pretty sure it should just be inside your FENRIR folder. Alternatively you could try commenting out lines 8 through 18 in your _settings.scss but only if you do not need the foundation components

Comment: Ok, I must use the command cd F:/dropbox/.../FENRIR/css to get into the right folder ? Then, put _settings.scss and app.scss in the folder. Then wait, and it works ?

Comment: No no I am afraid my instructions only seem to be confusing you further. How familiar are you with web-design and coding practices?

you would use the command promot to go to f:/dropbox..../scss and run the "sass --watch app.scss:app.css"

Now once this whole thing finishes compiling after a save copy your app.css file from the SCSS folder and paste it to your CSS folder. That should show you the results of the changes you made to the styling of the site.

Comment: Yes I'm student in Webdesign... But still, I don't understand why is there a FOUNDATION folder, where it should go, and with what in it ? I'm trying everything you tell me, without success. I've pull out every @import (by //commenting) and now app.css is empty :(

Comment: Foundation is just a web framework for building websites. Comes with a ton of prebuilt stuff, similar to bootstrap. If you are not interested in using foundation at all just go to the _settings.scss file and comment out all the lines that are calling for foundation/components...

What other @imports did you have there? looking at your file structure I don't see anything else that could really be imported other than foundation.

you could try downloading the foundation framework and extracting the foundation folder directly into FERNIR and uncomment the imports.

Comment: I want to use Foundation. I tried to import the folder downloaded from Foundation website. Here is the result on index.php : http://puu.sh/7KlKy.png | It seems like he can't find everything I need from Foundation : var and functions. And I don't get why, I created this folder FROM the command : foundation new FENRIR. It should have created everything right ?

Comment: Yeah sorry I cannot really help you with that. I am not that familiar with foundation I personally do not use frameworks like that just custom code 90% of it.

Comment: Well, you did helped me. I tried an other way. Now I understood using Grunt isn't the regular way. I typed "grunt" instead of "--watch" and BABOUM it edits a (visibly) working app.css ! (enventually). I'm trying this right now :)

Comment: Awesome! Well I am glad you got it figured out now =) good luck with the project and welcome to the various challenges of web-design! Don't forget to upvote the answer!

Comment: Can't upvote (I need more "reputation"), but I marked as resolved, thank you.